# Event Handler loose event in Firefox when AJAX DHTML

Tags: ajax, firefox, event-handling, dhtml

I have a problem with an event handler used to resort a table with the tab key putting an input cel or an select box in it to edit data in MySQL

The method is captured by the event handler, the key pressed is validated, if  TAB, it will continue with data validation if valid, it reach the database to uptade search for the next valid cell to insert either an nput or a select box.

The problem is that the code is not working in Firefox. When the row ends and it have to insert the select box the event handler seems to loose the event and ne next focused element jumps to the next element losing the event handler function.

Testing with firebug I find that the code breaks inside the keyhandler function when the element that fires the event is replaced with a text value. More extrange is that the ajax element (a select list) that supposed to be inserted dynamicaly appears for a moment into the screen and then disappears. Then I have tried to remove the element with removeChild method and then insert with innerHTML, but still not working.

```
        The table code
        <p style='text-align:center'>
        <legend><strong>PRODUTOS</strong></legend></p>

        <table class='resultados' id='produtos'>
          <tr><th style='display:none'>Código</th>
            <th style='text-align:right'>Grupo</th>
            <th style='text-align:center'>Marca</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th style='text-align:right'>Preço sugerido</th>
            <th><img src='../../../imagens/detalhes/detalhes.png' /></th>
            <th><img src='../../../imagens/img.png' /></th>
            <th><img src='../../../imagens/apaga/apaga.png' /></th>
          </tr>

        <tr class='alt'>
        <td style='display:none' id='codproduto1' title='codproduto'>79</td>

        <td style='text-align:right' title='Grupo' name='descgrupo' id='descgrupo1' onclick='adlg(this);' >ATUALIZAÇÕES</td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Marca' name='marca' id='marca1' onclick='adinp(this);'  >    MARCA</td>

        <td title='Descrição' name='descproduto' id='descproduto1' onclick='adinp(this);' >PRODUTO</td>

        <td style='text-align:right' title='Preço sugerido' name='precos' id='precos1' onclick='adinp(this);' >12,00</td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Detalhes Produto' id='detfila1' ><input type='image' src='../../../imagens/detalhes/detalhes.png'  onclick='exdetp(this);' /></td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Imagem Produto' id='imgfila1' ><input type='image'  src='../../../imagens/img.png' onclick='imgProduto(this);' /></td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Apagar Fila' id='apfila1' ><input type='image' src='../../../imagens/apaga/apaga.png' onclick='apProduto(this);' /></td>
    </tr>

        <tr class=''>
        <td style='display:none' id='codproduto2' title='codproduto'>81</td>
        <td style='text-align:right' title='Grupo' name='descgrupo' id='descgrupo2' onclick='adlg(this);' >ATUALIZAÇÕES</td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Marca' name='marca' id='marca2' onclick='adinp(this);'  >MARCA</td>

        <td title='Descrição' name='descproduto' id='descproduto2' onclick='adinp(this);' >PRODUTO2</td>

        <td style='text-align:right' title='Preço sugerido' name='precos' id='precos2' onclick='adinp(this);' >54,00</td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Detalhes Produto' id='detfila2' ><input type='image' src='../../../imagens/detalhes/detalhes.png'  onclick='exdetp(this);' /></td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Imagem Produto' id='imgfila2' ><input type='image' src='../../../imagens/img.png' onclick='imgProduto(this);' /></td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Apagar Fila' id='apfila2' ><input type='image' src='../../../imagens/apaga/apaga.png' onclick='apProduto(this);' /></td>
    </tr>


        <tr class='alt'>
        <td style='display:none' id='codproduto3' title='codproduto'>80</td>

        <td style='text-align:right' title='Grupo' name='descgrupo' id='descgrupo3' onclick='adlg(this);' >NOVO GRUPO 4</td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Marca' name='marca' id='marca3' onclick='adinp(this);'  >MARCA</td>

        <td title='Descrição' name='descproduto' id='descproduto3' onclick='adinp(this);' >PRODUTO3</td>

        <td style='text-align:right' title='Preço sugerido' name='precos' id='precos3' onclick='adinp(this);' >23,40</td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Detalhes Produto' id='detfila3' ><input type='image' src='../../../imagens/detalhes/detalhes.png'  onclick='exdetp(this);' /></td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Imagem Produto' id='imgfila3' ><input type='image' src='../../../imagens/img.png' onclick='imgProduto(this);' /></td>

        <td style='text-align:center' title='Apagar Fila' id='apfila3' ><input type='image' src='../../../imagens/apaga/apaga.png' onclick='apProduto(this);' /></td>
        </tr>
        </table> 

    The Javascript functions 


        /*ADD THE SELECT BOX OF  GROUPS*/
        function adlg (cell){
      ValueCell = cell.innerHTML;//Value from the cell
      var aPag = 'include/php/produtos/combo/combogrupo.php';
      var fat="&dados="+ValueCell;
      ajax(aPag,fat,false);
      if (oPed.readyState==4 && oPed.status==200){
        document.getElementById(cell.id).innerHTML=oPed.responseText;
        var myInput = document.getElementById("cel");/*Select box of the product groups*/
        myInput.focus();   
        adescuta('keydown','onkeydown',segtp,myInput);/* Adds the listen event */
      }     
        }
        /*ADDS THE LISTEN EVENT TO THE INPUT OR COMBO BOX------*/
        function adescuta(evento1, evento2, keyhand, myInput){
        /*events, function Input*/
      if(myInput.addEventListener )myInput.addEventListener(evento1,keyhand ,true);
      else if(myInput.attachEvent ) myInput.attachEvent(evento2,keyhand); 
    }
        /*------KEY HANDLER FOR PRODUCTS TABLE*/
       function segtp(e) {        
      var TABKEY = 9;   
      var ESCKEY = 27;   
      var ENTERKEY = 13;
      var pad;
      if(e.keyCode == TABKEY || e.keyCode==ENTERKEY) {
        stope(e);//Deter o evento por defeito
        var input= document.getElementById('cel');
        var cel= pegceldoi(input);
        var attonblur=input.getAttribute('onblur');
        var getnode=input.onblur='';
        if(ValueCell!=input.value){      
          err=atbdp(input);//update in database
          if (err!=true){
           alert (err);
           input.focus();
           input.setAttribute('onblur',attonblur);
           return false;
          }else{
            pad=/precos.+/;//
            if (pad.test(cel.id))input.value=number_format(numjs(input.value),2,',','.');
            cel.innerHTML=input.value.toUpperCase();
          }
        }else cel.innerHTML=ValueCell;
        if (e.keyCode== TABKEY){
          cel = percorretabela(cel,'produtos');/*look for valid cel*/
          pad=/descgrupo.+/;
          if(pad.test(cel.id))  adlg(cel);/*Add a select box*/
          else adinp(cel);// /*Add an input box*/
        }
        }
        }
        /*UPDATE */

        function atbdp(input){
          var padsf= new Array(/codproduto.+/,/marca.+/,/descproduto.+/,/descgrupo.+/,/precos.+/);//Padrões da fila
        var dadoscel=input.value;//Data
        var cel=pegceldoi(input);//Cell
        pad=/marca.+/;//Pattern exclude
        if(!pad.test(cel.id)&& vazio(dadoscel)==false) return 'Por favor preencha os dados do registro';//If input not filled
      var aPag = 'include/php/produtos/atualiza/atprodutos.php';
      var produto= pegvf(input,padsf,'produtos');/*patterns of the row*/ fat="&codproduto="+produto[0]+"&marca="+produto[1]+"&descproduto="+produto[2]+"&descgrupo="+produto[3]+"&precos="+numjs(produto[4]);
      ajax(aPag,fat,false);
      if (oPed.readyState==4 && oPed.status==200){
        if(oPed.responseText!='') return oPed.responseText;
        else return true;
      }
    }
    /*---------------AJAX*/
    function ajax(aPag,dados,bool){
      var oRand = parseInt (Math.random()*99999999999999);
      var fNovo="rand="+oRand+dados
      var oURL = aPag;
      oPed=  getXMLHTTPRequest ();
      oPed.open ("POST", oURL, bool);
      oPed.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   // Setando Content-type
      oPed.setRequestHeader("Content-length", fNovo.length);
      oPed.send(fNovo);
    }
    /*ADD INPUT TO THE TABLE */
    function adinp (cell){/*Cell that called the function*/
      var id = cell.id;//Identficador da célula clikada
      ValueCell = cell.innerHTML;/*Value from the cell*/
      var valin="value='"+ValueCell+"'";
      var longInput='', size='';//Tamanho máximo e tamanho do input
      var pad=/marca.+/;//Padrão de ndetificação da célula da marca
      if (pad.test(id)){
        longInput="maxlength='15'";
        size="size='13'";
      }else{
        pad=/descproduto.+/;
        if (pad.test(id)){
          longInput="maxlength='145'";
          size="size='45'";
        }else{
          longInput="maxlength='14'";
          size="size='14'";
          valin="value='"+numsim(ValueCell)+"'";
        }
      }
      cell.innerHTML = "<form name='produtos' style='margin:0; padding:0; padding-left:0; margin-left:0; position:relative'"
      +" onsubmit=' return false;'><input style='margin-left:2px; padding-left:2px' id='cel'"
      +" onblur='atpb(this);'"//Update on blur
      +" onclick='event.cancelBubble=true;'" 
      +" type='text' "
      +valin+" "
      +longInput+" "+size+" /><div class='campoexiste' id='existe'></div></form>";
      document.getElementById('cel').focus();
      var myInput = document.getElementById("cel");  
      adescuta('keydown','onkeydown',segtp,myInput); }
    /*----------------STOP EVENT----------------------------*/
    function stope(e){//Deter o evento por defeito
      if(e.preventDefault)  e.preventDefault();
      else{
        e.stop();
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.stopPropagation();        
      }
    }
    /*--------GET VALUES FROM ROW*/
    function pegvf(input,padsfila,nomtab){//Input, array com os padrões da fila, nome da tabela
      var vfila=new Array;//Valores da fila
      var cel=pegceldoi(input);//Célula que contém o input
      var idfila=cel.parentNode.rowIndex;//Índice da fila da célula
      var x;//Contador do array contador de colunas
        for (x in padsfila){
          if (padsfila[x].test(cel.id))vfila.push(input.value);
          else vfila.push(pegvalcel(padsfila[x],idfila,nomtab));
        }
      return vfila
    }
    ARCHIVO PHP
    Combogrupos.php
    <? 
    /*-----------------SELECT BOX OF----GROUPS*/
    $dados = addslashes(trim(utf8_decode($_POST['dados'])));//Nome do grupo que estava na célula
    $stl="style='margin-left:2px;padding-left:2px'";//Estilo da lista
    $atob="onblur='atpb(this);'";//Função atualiza on blur
    $occb="onclick='event.cancelBubble=true;'";//Cancela eventos bubble do evento click
    $lig="<select id='cel' $stl $atob $occb >";//Lista grupos
    $link=mysql_connect('localhost', '','');
    $db = mysql_select_db("fbinfo",$link);
    $query="SELECT * FROM gruposproduto";
    $res = mysql_query($query,$link);
    echo mysql_error();
    $num=mysql_num_rows($res);
    $sel;//Opção selecionada
    if ($num>0){
      $lig.="<option value='null'>Seleccione um grupo</option>";
      while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_BOTH)){
          if ($fila['descgrupo']==$dados)$sel="selected='selected'";
          else $sel='';
          $lig.="<option $sel value='".$fila['descgrupo']."'>".$fila['descgrupo']."</option>";
      }
    }else{
      $lig.="<option value='null'>Não há grupos</option>";
    }
    $lig.="</select><div id='existe'></div>";
    mysql_close($link);
    echo $lig;
    ?>
    Atprodutos.php
    <? 
    /*-----------UPDATE PRODUCTS*/
    include ('../../util/upper/upper.php');//Função que passa as letras para caixa alta
    foreach ($_POST as &$value)$value=utf8_decode(upper($value));//Decodifica as informações da página 
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','fbi02');
    $db = mysql_select_db("fbinfo",$link);
    $query= "SELECT codproduto FROM produtos JOIN gruposproduto AS g ON produtos.idgrupo= g.idgrupo WHERE descproduto='"
    .$_POST['descproduto']."' AND marca='".$_POST['marca']."' AND g.descgrupo='". $_POST['descgrupo']."'";
    $res = mysql_query($query,$link);
    echo mysql_error();
    $num=mysql_num_rows($res);
    if ($num>0){
      $fila=mysql_fetch_array($res);
      if ($fila['codproduto']!=$_POST['codproduto']){
        echo "O produto já existe";
        die;
      }
    }
    $query="UPDATE produtos SET descproduto='".$_POST['descproduto']."' , marca='".$_POST['marca']."' , precos=".$_POST['precos'].", idgrupo=(SELECT idgrupo FROM gruposproduto WHERE descgrupo='".$_POST['descgrupo']."') WHERE codproduto='".$_POST['codproduto']."'";
    $res = mysql_query($query,$link);
    echo mysql_error();
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was in the use the false for asyncronous method in the AJAX request that gets the list. 
Changing the asyncronous to true and setting the validation and the resort of the table out of the envent handler function solved the problem.

Thank you for all the help, I really appreciate all the coments and solutions that gave me a lot of ideas for finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace an HTML element via AJAX, you lose the event handler. You need to reinitialize the event handler after each load.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't undestand

I catch the event and use the e=event e.preventDefault(), e.stop()e.returnValue = false,  e.stopPropagation() methods

This should stop the event in both IE and Firefox, then use a function to resort the table and when the next valid cell is found the ajax function is called. However, why if this function is called inside an event handler it lose the scope and aborts in firefox? How could the event be reinitialized after being stoped?

The chain of functions is

function segtp(e) => stope(e) => percorretabela(cel,'produtos')=>adlg(cel)=lose

Comment: How can I renitialize the event Handler?

Comment: Re-run the same code you used to hook up the event handler the first time.

Comment: Do you mean to run the segtp(event) function after the XMLHTTP.open?

Comment: Take a look as jQuery's .live() functionlaity. It will help.

Comment: I have tried live() method this way:
$(myInput).live("keypress",myfunction); //Does not work

Comment: The live method takes a lot longer, causes a random position in the table on IE and in firebug loses the debugging line after a simple cell.textContent="ABC"; then the ajax is works once and debugger never more until Firefox restart