# `String.fromCharCode(keyCode)` doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyevent

`String.fromCharCode(keyCode)` doesn't work in Firefox.

For example

- I press the semicolon key and it throws the 1/4 sign.
- The number pad throws letters.

I am using this to do some field validation, because the `event.key` attrubute is not supported in FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycode is the numeric identifier of the key on the keyboard.  It's pretty much completely unrelated to the charcode, which is the Unicode codepoint of the character produced.

So using a keycode as an argument to fromCharCode will almost certainly give you garbage.

What are you actually trying to do with the keycode, and why?

Comment: I am trying to do some validation on key down for numbers and semicolon

Comment: Why from keydown and not keypress?

Comment: because keypress allows the string to appear in the box, I am tryingo to block non allowed characters

Comment: If you preventDefault the keypress event, that will _not_ allow the character to appear in the box.

Comment: You are right, beside, the String.fromCharCode (eventkeypress.keyCode) is giving right values, so I can validate numpad also. Thank you!

Comment: I have another unanswered question could you please take a look?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082662/event-handler-loose-event-in-firefox-when-ajax-dhtml

Answer (score 2):

Use **event.which** for FF. You can refer to this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of event.keyCode try event.charCode. It will work in chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#Name_Var').keypress(function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var charCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    // FireFox key Del - Supr - Up - Down - Left - Right
    if (event.key !== undefined && event.charCode === 0) {
        return;
    }
    //Only Num
    if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(charStr)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    //Num and letters 
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(charStr)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```